# All rows except row 1 are shown

Tags: php, mysql

When I select some data from my database (MySQL), it shows all the rows except the first one. How to fix it?

**Code**

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, title, image, description, tekst, address, website, telephone, email, openinghours FROM ExperienceUtrecht";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<table border='1'> <tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Title</th> <th>Image</th> <th>Description</th> <th>Tekst</th> <th>Address</th> <th>Website</th> <th>Telephone</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Opening Hours</th> </tr>"; while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo "<tr>"; echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['image'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['tekst'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['website'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['telephone'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['openinghours'] . "</td>"; echo "</tr>"; } echo "</table>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: @clearshot66 That didn't changed anything of the outcome

Comment: declare a flag before `while`, `$flagFirstLine=true`, and check flag's value before `echo`, `if($flagFirstLine==true) continue;`. and set `flagFirstLine` to `false` after `echo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two while loops as @user2983401 pointed out. Get rid of the first one:

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, title, image, description, tekst, address, website, telephone, email, openinghours FROM ExperienceUtrecht";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
/*while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { Not needed*/
    echo "<table border='1'> <tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Title</th> <th>Image</th> <th>Description</th> <th>Tekst</th> <th>Address</th> <th>Website</th> <th>Telephone</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Opening Hours</th> </tr>"; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo "<tr>"; echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['image'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['tekst'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['website'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['telephone'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['openinghours'] . "</td>"; echo "</tr>"; } echo "</table>";
/*} Not needed*/
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You have two while loops. The first loop has moved The cursor to the first record. The second while loop moves the cursor again. 
Suggestion: Move the the table  tag and table heads directly into the If and remove the first loop.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

//it will work. your logics was good but unfortunately you did just simple mistake. you used two while loops to fetch same record.

//first while loop fetch first record and after inner loop run, and second record and continue record fetch and you tried to print this record.